# Special typography in lecture notes

Tags: typography

In some probability theory lecture notes I found on the internet, I noticed a special math typesetting, as you can see on the pictures below

[image]
[image]

The spacing between the brackets is bigger, integral sign is different, sum sign is more beautiful, brackets are of same thickness et cetera

Does anybody know what this package is called?

The link to the file . [click](http://www.win.tue.nl/~thulshof/2WS20/LectureNotes.pdf)

Comment: It seems to use MnSymbol. Is that what you mean?